# use $lt or $gt operator in mongodb queries

Tags: mongodb

My collection structure**"countcollection"** is looks as below

```
{
"limitcount": 10000,
"currentcount": 100
}
```

I want to right the mongoquery that able to compare the `currentcount<($lt)limitcount` 
or `currentcount>($gt)limitcount`.

First, i wrote the mongo query as below

```
db.countcollection.find({"currentcount":{$lt:{"limitcount"}}});
db.countcollection.find({"currentcount":{$gt:{"limitcount"}}});
```

but it's failed to execute .

please give your input for this mongoquery.

thanks in advance .

javaamtho.

Answer (score 5):

As Bugai13 said, you can't do a comparison on 2 fields in a query.

The problem with $where is performance - as that is a javascript function that will be executed for every document so it will have to scan through every one.

So, you could store another field (that you could then index) alongside those existing fields

e.g.

```
{
"limitcount": 10000,
"currentcount": 100,
"remainingcount" : 9900
}
```

so you could then query on the new field instead:

```
db.countcollection.find({"remainingcount" : {$gt : 0}})
db.countcollection.find({"remainingcount" : {$lt : 0}})
```

Comment: i tried with suggest @Bugai13 javascript expression way mongoquery and it's worked .thanks lots ..

Comment: yeah, in mongodb always better create 'extra' field. + 1

Answer (score 3):

You can't do what you want using simple query(like you have tried above). There is such bug in [mongodb jira](http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2702) and you can vote up for this.

I suppose you shoud use [javascript expression](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-JavascriptExpressionsand%7B%7B%24where%7D%7D) like this:

```
db.countcollection.find( { $where: "this.currentcount < this.limitcount" } );
```

Hope this help.

Comment: @javaamtho: At stackoverlow we are say 'thanks' with accepted answer and vote up ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$gt:{"limitcount"}}
```

does not make any sense since you are comparing against the string limitcount. If you want to compare against a pre-defined variable, use the variable but something with quotes around it. Why did you choose this strange syntax?

Comment: no no ..i want to compare the value of those two field.i means compare 100$lt10000.

Comment: You can not compare one field against another one using some $ operator. You need to use the $where clause here.